# NPM script to build typescript not working

Tags: typescript, windows, npm, visual-studio-code

[UPDATE]

This issue was originally solved by uninstalling `tsc` with `npm uninstall tsc` (as suggested by the marked answer). However, the issue came back and after a long time had passed I tried using Windows Server for Linux (WSL) with VSCode. It did the trick immediately, so that is the solution I've stuck with.

---

I am having an issue running the `tsc` command using an NPM script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc"
},
```

**Running `tsc` in the windows command terminal runs fine, but running `tsc` using the NPM script does not.** When I run `tsc` in the NPM script, I get the following in the command console:

```
> npm run build

> skill-tree@1.0.0 build
> tsc

'D\skill-tree\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Documents\~College\~Coding\tsc\bin\tsc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Documents\~College\~Coding\D&D\skill-tree
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c tsc

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\layto\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-03T13_19_01_935Z-debug.log
```

I have noted that it says `Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Documents\~College\~Coding\tsc\bin\tsc'` and I think that is the root of the problem because such a folder `~Coding\tsc` does not exist, but I don't understand why the script is attempting to access the folder, nor do I know how to fix it.

Here is my tsconfig file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNEXT",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./.vscode",
    "./templates"
  ]
}
```

Here is my package file:

```json
{
  "name": "skill-tree",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "Layton Burchell",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^3.6.9",
    "tsc": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

Here is the log file:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\layto\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'build'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.5.2
2 info using node@v15.8.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\layto\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:D:\Documents\~College\~Coding\D&D\skill-tree\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\layto\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
19 verbose npm-session cdea02db6803097a
20 timing npm:load Completed in 19ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 105ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\layto\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
23 verbose pkgid skill-tree@1.0.0
24 verbose cwd D:\Documents\~College\~Coding\D&D\skill-tree
25 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
26 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\layto\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
27 verbose node v15.8.0
28 verbose npm  v7.5.2
29 error code 1
30 error path D:\Documents\~College\~Coding\D&D\skill-tree
31 error command failed
32 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c tsc
33 verbose exit 1
```

I have tried:

- Globally installing typescript with `npm i typescript -g`
- Reinstalling typescript locally with `npm i typescript --save-dev`
- Running `npx tsc` instead of just `tsc` in the windows console and npm script (both failed with the same error shown above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `tsc` package (which is listed in your `devDependencies`). It's not from Microsoft. The `tsc` command line tool comes with the `typescript` node package.

So uninstall `tsc` and retry.

Comment: I installed `tsc` to try and fix this issue, no idea how this was the solution. Thanks though, massive help.

Comment: Glad it helped. I guess you maybe tried something else too which actually fixed the issue but at the same time installed `tsc` which broke it again.